# Firebase -How to handle pagination if the key set to paginate from has been deleted

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I use the pagination method at the bottom of this question which works fine. Once the `startKey` is initialized with a `key` from the `db` that's the point at which the next pagination will occur from and the next set of posts (children) will get appended to the datasource.

[image]

I realized that if that `key` got deleted by the initial user who posted it, then once I try to paginate from that `key` since it doesn't exist the children that would get appended if it was there wouldn't get appended because they wouldn't be accessible (they're accessible based on that key).

[image]

The only thing I could think of was to first check if the key `exists()` and if it doesn't just start everything over from the beginning:

```
if !snapshot.exists() {

     self?.startKey = nil
     self?.datasource.removeAll()
     self?.collectionView.reloadData()
     self?.handlePagination()                    
     return
 }
```

It works fine but it's not the most fluid user experience because I'd rather just pull the posts prior to the deleted key (I have no prior reference to them).

[image]

A possibility is to just keep an array of all the previous keys and just loop through them but there's always a minute chance that those keys can get deleted by the users who posted them also.

**Any ideas of how to get around this?**

```
var startKey: String?

func handlePagination() {

    if startKey == nil {

        Database...Ref.child("posts")
          .queryOrderedByKey()
          .queryLimited(toLast: 7)
          .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    // append child to datasource
            }
            self?.startKey = children.key
        })

    } else {

        Database...Ref.child("posts")
          .queryOrderedByKey()
          .queryEnding(atValue: startKey!)
          .queryLimited(toLast: 8)
          .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self](snapshot) in

            if !snapshot.exists() {

                self?.startKey = nil
                self?.datasource.removeAll()
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                self?.handlePagination()                    
                return
            }

            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return}

            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                // insert child in datasource at startIndex
            }
            self?.startKey = children.key
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: "there's always a minute chance that those keys can get deleted by the users who posted them also" In that case you'd end up showing the (new) first results. That seems to be the correct behavior for this (unlikely) situation, doesn't it?

Comment: Lmao, I know it’s a very very very very highly unlikely situation that all the keys would get deleted but it does have a sliver of a chance of happening (if all those users deleted all those posts I have much bigger problems to worry about). Maybe I’m overthinking the situation . What do you mean by “in that case you’d end up showing the new results first”? You lost me with that one

Comment: You're saying that you could keep the keys of the current page, and just loop through until you find an item that was not deleted. In the case that all have been deleted, you'd reach the end of the list of keys, and should create a new query that doesn't have a `startAt()`. This will give you the first X items, which is the correct behavior in that case I think.

Comment: In general though: dealing with realtime and pagination is really hard, which is the main reason the paging adapters in FirebaseUI don't do realtime updates.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. I literally just started learning paginating last week, in the process I saw that are so many different situations that can occur and so many different scenarios to even set up the pagination that I wasn’t sure if I was going about it incorrectly. You just gave me some reassurance that it wasn’t just me. I definitely see the difficulty. Honestly the easiest contingency if it doesn’t exist is to just start everything over from the beginning. Saying what you said I’m just going to keep it simple. If the app grows I’ll worry about all that other stuff later. As usual thanks 

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get it working. I'll probably repost my comments as some sort of answer, just so we can give this post some closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there's always a minute chance that those keys can get deleted by the users who posted them also

You're saying that you could keep the keys of the current page, and just loop through until you find an item that was not deleted. In the case that all have been deleted, you'd reach the end of the list of keys, and should create a new query that doesn't have a startAt(). This will give you the first X items, which is the correct behavior in that case I think.

In general though: dealing with realtime and pagination is really hard, which is the main reason the paging adapters in FirebaseUI don't do realtime updates.